# Website upload prevent hacking

Tags: php, security, upload

There's an upload form on my website. I'm actually not really including or excluding file types.

Instead I'm using this:

```
$fileUploadName = $target_dir.md5(uniqid($target_file.rand(),true)).".".$imageFileType;
```

That will keep the file type but change the file name to some random cryptic like `790cd5a974bf570ff6a303c3dc5be90f`.

This way a hacker cannot upload a `hack.php` file and the open it with `www.example.com/uploaded_files/hack.php` because it has changed to e.g. `790cd5a974bf570ff6a303c3dc5be90f.php`. In my view it's completely safe this way. Am I right that it's safe this way?

I think only a self-executing-file could be a problem. Do self-executing-files even exist?

Comment: Applying [Kerckhoff's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs's_principle) "the attacker knows everything about the system except the (cryptographic) key", your attacker may know that you use an MD5 checksum of the file name and therefore could deduce the uploaded file name.

Comment: Why, under any circumstances, would you allow execution of uploaded files?

Comment: @miken32 I don't understand what you mean. Of course I want to avoid a hacker can upload a file and then excute. To avoid this I'm changing the real file name in something cryptic with md5(uniqid($filename)). This way, I hope, a hacker cannot call and excute the file via browser because he don't know the (actual) file name. This, of course, wouldn't work if it's a self-execution-file. But do. self-execution-files even exist?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think you missed I'm mixing `MD5`, `uniqid()` and `$target_file`. I think this should be save enough, uncrackable, not? – David 21 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

You should also eighter check the mime type of the file uploaded and the extension (although that can easily be faked on upload).
If you expect only images, you could also check for image width and length parameters by executing a script like this:

```
$size = getimagesize($target_file);
```

If this does not return proper values, it's no image file.

You might want to inform yourself about dangerous graphics like Gifar too.

Comment: Okay, but why should I do additionally checks? User won't be able to call/open the uploaded file, or will he?

Comment: I would sanitize every upload as much as possible. If you expect image files, I'd check for image files by using getimagesize for example.
There are a lot of circumstances where somebody could actually reach the file uploaded. A webserver update / misconfiguration could enable directory browsing for example.
Or somebody could just try a brute force attack to find files on the server (given they can be executed from the web).

Comment: Usually people want to do something with the files uploaded later. Download them, display them somewhere. Even a simple optimizing script for files or some index service could trigger the files and get it executed if circumstances allow it.

Comment: The uploaded files are only for me (the website owner). The user (or any user) has no access after uploading.

Comment: If nothing ever happens with these files again and they are locked away securely your solution should be fine I think.

Comment: Yes, you're right. User can only upload and I access these files by uploading from my server via FTP. So there's no more access. I think the file name should be cryptic enough with this: `md5(uniqid($target_file.rand(),true))`. This way a hacker would not be able to call it. P.S.: Do self-executing-files exist?

Comment: Not as far as I know. You might want to checkout this discussion about the topic: http://superuser.com/questions/642242/self-executing-files

There must always be a trigger to get the file executed. But the trigger itself can be anything - even a indexing service (like windows does for files and folders) or soe optimization program like I described above.
So the executing might even be triggered by the OS instead of you or an attacker. That's why I'd sanitize all uploaded files if possible.

Comment: New hacking possibilities show up every day - iphones can be compromised by a simple SMS now. Files could always be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Put uploaded files in there own folder like `/etc/web/uploads/<Random>` (../uploads) while the website root is at `/etc/web/public/` or if you can use `.htaccess` create one in the uploads folder and put `Deny from all`
Also uniqid and rand does not generate cryptographically secure values I would also check that the uploaded file is an image anyway [Link to someones isimage function](http://www.binarytides.com/php-check-if-file-is-an-image/)  http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Use `file_get_contents` to get the users image